# Is there any simple way to multiply cv::Rect size and coordinates?

Tags: c++, opencv

Let's say I have 2 rectangle. I want the second rectangle to be twice bigger than the first rectangle and the position of x,y also twice bigger.

```
cv::Rect r1=Rect(10,20,40,60);
cv::Rect r2 = r1 * 2;  //this won't work
```

Setting the rectangle 2 parameter 1 by 1 will work

```
r2.height = r1.height * 2;
r2.width = r1.height * 2;
r2.x = r1.x * 2;
r2.y = r2.y * 2;
```

It works, but is there any simpler way to do it (like single line code)?

Comment: Not according to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html), you could write your own function but this seems relatively specialised since you're multiplying the position?

Comment: did you try cv::Rect r2 = r1 * cv::Size(2,2); ? or cv::Rect r2 = r1 +cv::Size(width, height) to translate, rect + cv::Point(x,y) should work.

Comment: You are going to multiply positions `x,y` what do you mean by multiplying the positions? For resizing you can multiply the `width, height`.

Comment: Multiplying a rectangle by two does not really have a clear meaning; where should the origin be? (0, 0)? Bottom-left? Centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this, this might be the shortest way:

```
cv::Rect r1=Rect(10,20,40,60);
cv::Rect r2(r1.tl() * 2, r1.br() * 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can overload the `*` operator:

```
cv::Rect operator*(cv::Rect r, double scale) {
    r.height *= scale;
    r.width *= scale;
    r.x *= scale;
    r.y *= scale;
    return r;
}
```

And then you can multiply rectangles directly:

```
Rect r2 = Rect(10, 20, 40, 60) * 2;
```

Comment: The multiplying position did not make sense, it is why OpenCV does not provide such operator overload. The multiplying position does not mean resizing as OP asks.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Admittedly, I don't think something like a multiplication operator is a good idea, since that sort of multiplication is not a common case. But the op does say "the first rectangle and the position of x,y also twice bigger.".

Comment: @George If you check the comments under the OP's question, you will see that the others also think that it is wrong to resize a Rectangle by multiplying the position, so not only the OP is wrong in its question (as he wants to resize, not reposition) but also the answer according to this is also does not make sense. Resizing and repositioning are two different concepts. Which you cannot do it at once.

Comment: It’s just a scaling operation. And when you scale something you have to multiply both position and size by the same factor.

Comment: @JorgePerez Then what about position `0,0`?  Or What about `x=200` while `width=300` and when you multiply it by `2` now `x=400` it will go out of scope and will throw an exception, but `width` still can be drawn without exception.

Comment: When you scale a shape - any shape - you treat the points along the shape as vectors, and scale them all by the same scale factor. This is equivalent to multiplying the position, width, and height by the same factor.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil My point is that the op never mentions scaling, or resizing.  "Resizing and repositioning are two different concepts." Feels irrelevant given the information we've got.

Comment: He specifically wants to multiply both the size, and the coordinates. This is exactly what scaling is.

Comment: @George OP says: "I want the second rectangle to be twice bigger than the first rectangle and the position of x,y also twice bigger", then how could you make the position twice bigger? If you want to make the position bigger then the `x` goes to be smaller, for e.g: the position `100,100` when you make it bigger you should go to position `50, 50`, Or `0,0`, so the `x,y` got smaller if you multiply it by 2 then it will get bigger which leads the Rect to become smaller. So scaling the size and the position is an opposite operation.

Comment: To make the position bigger, you multiply it by the scale factor. So to make the position twice as big, you multiply it by 2. If I’m rendering multiple shapes at once, to render them twice as big, I just multiply all positions by 2, and all sizes by 2. If I don’t multiply the position by 2, then previously disjoint shapes might overlap. But my multiplying *everything* by 2, the image displayed on screen is rendered twice as big

Comment: @BahramdunAdil  sorry for late reply and thx for the discussion, let me straight the things, actually I have 2 frames, 1 is twice bigger than the first one. So I want to create rectangle that twice bigger that has same x,y proportion (I just don't know what's the official term of it), I should have mentioned that in the question, sorry.

Comment: That's known as scaling, and the solution I gave will do exactly that!

Comment: @JorgePerez In your solution, the `x, y` has been changed, OP wants the same `x, y` so the Rect will move to a new position.

Comment: OP literally just commented that he wants the same x,y proportional to the size of the rectangle because he’s scaling up a frame! You have to scale the x and y by multiplying them by the scale factor